# How to make UILabel contents non localizible when genetating string via ibtool?

Tags: ios, localization, interface-builder, xib

I have some labels on my xib. Some of them are not need to be localized. When i generate strings file via ibtool all labels content included in result file. 
How can i exclude some UI objects in IB from localization when generate strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to annotate the content of your nib/xib files so that ibtool's `--export-strings-file` command ignores certain strings.

You could instead opt to use the `--export-xliff` option and then edit the XLIFF file to lock segments that must not be translated (attribute `translate="no"`) before sending them out to be localized in all your languages. That's probably only worth doing if the localizers use a XLIFF-compatible CAT tool though.