# Excluding place holder texts from localisations

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When I design a cell layout I usually assign a sample text, e.g. 'John Appleseed' to a 'name' label so I can easily see where the field is on the layout and check the composition. Otherwise there is an empty label on a white background. Obviously this text does not need to be translated as it will be always replaced by another value at runtime.

Is there any property I can set in the Object Inspector to exclude this text from .strings / XLIFF file? Translators usually charge per word, so I don't want to send those texts for translation.

For the time being I use '~' prefix and then remove those texts using a Ruby script, but I was wondering whether there is an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you are using `ibtool` (and you do not really have an alternative) you cannot exclude words directly.

What you can do, is to edit the `XLIFF` file after you export it and add the attribute `translate="no"` on the strings you want to exclude. You should make sure that your translators use a XLIFF-compatible tool to translate.

But, imho, this is not any better than your way.

Also see [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920633/mark-text-in-interface-builder-as-not-needing-translation), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609495/how-to-make-uilabel-contents-non-localizible-when-genetating-string-via-ibtool) and ibtool's [manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html).

Comment: Do I have to hand-edit the xliff file to say `translate="no"` every single time I export it, or if I re-import the edited xliff will Xcode keep that attribute the next time I export?